# Cannot find module Node and Typescript Error

Tags: node.js, typescript

I import router like,
`import router from "user/routes";` in index.ts

and this gives me below error like this when I run my Project

```
Error: Cannot find module 'user/routes'
Require stack:
- /Users/icebit-imac3/Node Test/src/index.ts
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (/Users/icebit-imac3/Node Test/node_modules/@cspotcode/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:811:30)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/icebit-imac3/Node Test/src/index.ts:3:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/icebit-imac3/Node Test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1597:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/icebit-imac3/Node Test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1600:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/icebit-imac3/Node Test/src/index.ts' ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Project Directory Structure

```
Node Test
|-src
| |-middleware
| | |-datavalidation.ts
| | |-jwt.ts
| |-user
| | |-controller
| | | |-user.controller.ts
| | |-model
| | | |-user.model.ts
| | |-routes.ts
| |-index.ts
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2016",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "paths": {
        "user/*": [
          "src/user/*"
        ],
        "middleware/*": [
          "src/middleware/*"
        ]
      },
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "strict": true, 
      "skipLibCheck": true 
    },
    "include": [
      "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
```

Run Command
`"nodemon --watch 'src' -e ts,tsx --exec ts-node ./src"`

I also reviewed the typescript configuration for tsconfig.json file and make changes according to it, but still not works

Comment: I would suggest you to use [ts-node-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev). It is nodemon like package but for typescript projects.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but, ts-node-dev also gives the same error